# How to get first previous major pivots of the current bar in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for a way to get the first previous major pivots of the chart and current bar.
Consider the image below:

[image]

I don't want all pivots but just major pivots.

I'm newbie to Pine Script. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you can use is with Pine's pivot functions, as in this example from the usrman's page on [Colors](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Colors.html#conditional-coloring), where the number of bars each side of the pivot determines how "major" you want them to be:

```
//@version=4
study("Conditional colors", "", true)
int i_legs    = input(5, "Pivot Legs", minval = 1)
color i_c_pHi = input(color.olive, "High pivots")
color i_c_pLo = input(color.orange, "Low pivots")
// Intialize the pivot level variables.
var float pHi = na
var float pLo = na
// When a new pivot is detected, save its value.
pHi := nz(pivothigh(i_legs, i_legs), pHi)
pLo := nz(pivotlow( i_legs, i_legs), pLo)
// When a new pivot is detected, do not plot a color.
plot(pHi, "High", change(pHi) ? na : i_c_pHi, 2, plot.style_line)
plot(pLo, "Low",  change(pLo) ? na : i_c_pLo, 2, plot.style_line)
```

Alternatively, you can use pivots detected at a higher timeframe, as is done [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/VYzEUnYB-Pivots-MTF-LucF/).

Comment: You don't know how much I should say thanks to you!